# Undesired vertical padding in an html table

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I have a one row, three column table in html that has this unwanted vertical padding. I have three images, each one aligned to the left, one the center, and one to the right. I have tried setting the margins and padding to 0, but neither work. I highlighted the image and table with my browser cursor to show which padding is undesired. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

```
...
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    cellpadding: 0;
  }
  tr {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    word-wrap:break-word;
  }
  td {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    word-wrap:break-word;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="left">
    </td>
    <td>
      <p style="text-align:center">
        <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="middle" >
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="right">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
...
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

It was the default paragraph element margin. I just added "margin:0;" to the style.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="left">
    </td>
    <td>
      <p style="text-align:center; margin:0;">
        <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="middle" >
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="right">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the image itself has padding? I'd check that first. If the table cell is fitting to the smiley, but the smiley has a white border, that'd do it.

Comment: there's maybe a pixel or two of padding in the image, but no where near the amount that is in the table. I've updated with a photo to show the image selected.

Answer (score 0):

You do seem to have the whole row of 42 pixels height, that makes me believe the unwanted padding is part of a picture itself which you've set to be exactly 42 pixels in height.

So, I've tried to force the row height to be of e.g. 60 pixels so that not only images are stretching the whole row to its dimensions and added some vertical-align and voilà... Worked for me:

```
<tr style="height: 60px; vertical-align: top;">
```

P.S. I saw your update... Looks weird until you didn't change size of a screenshot :) Anyway, try to specify vertical-align for a whole row, it might work for you.